# Failed to find "gl.h" on macOS 11.3

Tags: qt, opengl, cmake

I've got XCode 12.5 up and running on macOS 11.3 (M1 chip) in Github Actions as a self-hosted runner.

While my macOS workflow is able to find `gl.h` in the github-hosted machine just fine, my own self-hosted one reports this:

```
  CMake Error at /Users/administrator/actions-runner/_work/Mudlet/Qt/5.14.2/clang_64/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfigExtras.cmake:9 (message):
  Error:   Failed to find "gl.h" in
    "/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers;/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers".
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /Users/administrator/actions-runner/_work/Mudlet/Qt/5.14.2/clang_64/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfig.cmake:202 (include)
    3rdparty/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:555 (_find_package)
    /Users/administrator/actions-runner/_work/Mudlet/Qt/5.14.2/clang_64/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets/Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake:94 (find_package)
    3rdparty/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:555 (_find_package)
    /Users/administrator/actions-runner/_work/Mudlet/Qt/5.14.2/clang_64/lib/cmake/Qt5UiTools/Qt5UiToolsConfig.cmake:219 (find_package)
    3rdparty/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:555 (_find_package)
    3rdparty/edbee-lib/edbee-lib/CMakeLists.txt:177 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

The code responsible is [this line](https://github.com/Mudlet/edbee-lib/blob/e83b4883bc426a5c8a4b8085d61de2d92e9fa468/edbee-lib/CMakeLists.txt#L177):

```
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5UiTools REQUIRED)
```

What could be the reason that `gl.h` is not locatable?

Comment: "What could be the reason that `gl.h` is not locatable?" - Perhaps, you forgot to specify directories where this header should be searched. Please, show you **code**. Without it we unlikely will able to help you.

Comment: It's CMake that is looking for the header at configuration time, so just a FIND_PACKAGE call for Qt5UITools.

Comment: If solely `find_package(Qt5UITools)` triggers given problem, then add to the question post a code which contains just a given line. If given line itself doesn't reproduce the problem, then we need to be aware of that. BTW, where exactly OpenGL is installed on your machine?

Comment: I have no idea where OpenGL is installed on the machine - I'm not a daily macOS user. I did install XCode and the CLI tools however.

Answer (score 2):

I got this problem when I updated to MacOS Big Sur (11.6.2) when trying to make a qt app.

This was the error I got:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/Qt-5.5.1/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfigExtras.cmake:9 (message):
  Failed to find "gl.h" in
  "/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers;/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Qt-5.5.1/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfig.cmake:139 (include)
```

My google-fu found this from 2019 [https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/2208]
https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/2208 :

```
The new path to the framework is:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks
```

I looked, and gl.h was found in several places, including OpenGL.framework.

As a work-around, I changed the library path in /usr/local/Qt-5.5.1/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfigExtras.cmake:9 from:

```
set(_GL_INCDIRS "/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers" "/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers")
```

to:

```
set(_GL_INCDIRS "/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers" "/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers" "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks")
```

Answer (score 0):

> running on macOS 11.3 (M1 chip) in Github Actions as a self-hosted runner.

Try again with the latest version of self-hosted runners, since (Aug. 2022):

> ### [GitHub Actions: Self-hosted runners now support Apple M1 hardware](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-08-09-github-actions-self-hosted-runners-now-support-apple-m1-hardware/)
>
> Actions runner support for Apple silicon hardware, such as the M1 chip, is now generally available.
>
> This provides teams with the capability to run self-hosted macOS workflows in a macOS ARM64 runtime.
> Now the **[Actions runner](https://github.com/actions/runner)** supports M1 and the ARM64 runtime meaning developers can run it on their own M1 or M2 hardware.
>
> Based on initial testing, there are currently two issues to be aware of:
>
> - macOS ARM64 does not support node12.
>   Therefore, the runner will automatically use node16 to execute any javascript Action written for node12.
> - All actions provided by GitHub are compatible with the runner except for a known issue with `setup-python`. The fix for that can be [tracked here](https://github.com/actions/setup-python/issues/108).
>
> For additional information on how to set up a self-hosted macOS ARM64 runner, please refer to our [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/using-self-hosted-runners-in-a-workflow#using-default-labels-to-route-jobs).
> If you have any feedback or questions for Actions self-hosted Apple silicon support, you can submit an issue in the [runner repository](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues).